# Assigning values to multiple columns based on a single condition using Pandas (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

I have to create multiple new columns based on a single condition. I have a code that has multiple lines, is there a way to shorten or optimize the  below code, since I have to repeat it numerous times:

```
LOOKUP['Publisher']= np.where(LOOKUP['Subchannel'].str.contains("PROMO"),"Instagram",LOOKUP['Publisher'])
LOOKUP['Channel']= np.where(LOOKUP['Subchannel'].str.contains("PROMO"),"Social",LOOKUP['Channel'])
LOOKUP['Source']=  np.where(LOOKUP['Subchannel'].str.contains("PROMO"),"AA",LOOKUP['Source'])
```

Comment: You can use a for loop when your column name is the key, and your where condition is the value.

Comment: What is `LOOKUP` here, exactly?

Comment: The columns are already created right? Would give an error here otherwise

Comment: I have lookup as a dataframe. The columns don't pre-exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column doesn't exist already, you can try the following to avoid multiple where statements:

```
condition = LOOKUP['Subchannel'].str.contains("PROMO")
# for all those rows where condition is not satisfied, insert a blank
LOOKUP[['Publisher','Channel','Source']] = 
pd.DataFrame(np.where(condition[:, None], ['Instagram','Social','AA'], ['','','']))
```

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you earlier. I want to create new columns. The new columns dont pre-exist. Can you please suggest what would be change to the code?

Comment: @Newbie123 did you get a chance to try this?

Comment: Sorry, could not acknowledge earlier. The solution worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit confusing because it looks like you already have the columns you want to create. Are they pre-initialised with empty data or something similar?

I think what the other people is telling you is something like this:

```
cols = ['Publisher','Channel','Source', ...] # Name of the columns you want to iterate
values = ['Instagram', 'Social', 'AA', ...] # The values you want to yield after np.where()

for i in range(len(cols)):
    LOOKUP[cols[i]] = np.where(LOOKUP['Subchannel'].str.contains("PROMO"),values[i], LOOKUP[cols[i]])
```

This way you don't need to write many similar lines. Just update `cols` and `values` instead.

Comment: Sorry for not being very specific. I want to create new columns. The new columns dont pre-exist. Can you please suggest what would be the changes to the code if the columns dont pre=exist.

Comment: If the columns don't pre-exist, why are you using them inside ```np.where()```? Maybe you could try this: ```np.where(LOOKUP['Subchannel'].str.contains("PROMO"),values[i], '')```. This will add empty strings for the rows that don't match the condition.